# What is the name of this Korean mobile sports game?

Tags: game-identification

This is an android game from Korea or China (I am not sure about it). What is the name of this game and is it available in English or not? If anybody have link to download this game, please share. Here is a screenshot of game-play.

[image]

Comment: That's definitely Korean. You can tell because Korean has lots of circles, Chinese/Japanese have almost none.

Comment: Yes, those are Korean characters ([Hangul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The game is called [Extreme Football](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ninemgames.football&hl=en_US). It seems to only be available on Android devices.

Here are some other images of the game:

[image]